# Submitting form in javascript Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm working on laravel 5.4 project.I'm trying to submit form using form id from javascript.

```
document.getElementById('form1').submit();
```

This line of code I'm using in javascript to submit form. It gives me this error in console.

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a
>   function

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: It seems like the `document.getElementById('form1')` is not catching your form, are you sure you gave the form the property `id='form1'`?

Comment: <form id="form1" action="{{url('login')}}" method="POST">
yes this is my form code

Comment: On what basis are you trying to trigger the submit, is it on button click?

Comment: yes onclick I called js function and after performing some validations on form data I'm submitting my form using form id

Comment: Try to console log `document.getElementById('form1')` to check what element is being returned.

Comment: Thanks,Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
var formdata = document.getElementById("form1");
formdata.submit();
```

you can try this if you face error then please share your code i will help you for sure.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: formdata.submit is not a function
getting this error